# Will X-Forward-for and Accept-Language fields could be used for log forging?

Tags: java, fortify

I have my JavaEE code scanned by Fortify SCA, it have reported that my httpServletRequest .getLocale() and httpservletRequest.getHeader("X-forward-for") could cause log forging. Based on my knowledge, getLocale() would limit its data to locale type only, and X-forward-for field could only put IP. So there is NO WAY they could cause any "Log forging".

So I'd like to ask will they actually could be used for log forging? or this is just another Fortify's low-end programmer "think" it would?

Comment: What you describe those fields to contain is what they are thought for. However, since both locale and x-forwarded-for are basically text values a client could write almost anything into them. So if there is no validation you'd basically get those texts sent by the client and put them into your logs. You could test this with a simple endpoint that does some logging, calling it via Postman etc. and setting values for those headers yourself.

Comment: you can test the header by using curl, something like `curl -X GET "http://your-website.com/" -H "X-forward-for: lorem-ipsum-test"`.

Comment: @Thomas but getLocale() function should be able to limit it as locale only, isn't it? since java have limited its input, or it doesn't?

Comment: No, Java itself allows for arbitrary locale strings, try `System.out.println(new Locale("forged log"));`. Parsing from requests might apply _some_ logic so you can't put everything but you should still be able to get non-locale identifiers into a `Locale` instance.